# Conversion of DLL into readable format

Tags: dll

Can we convert the .dll file into any readable format (e.g. .TXT, .DOC etc). I have some data in .dll file but i don't know about the format of saved data in .dll file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the .dll file into any readable format"? Do you want to extract text resources of this dll? Remember that a dll , in essence, is a file generated from a source code and has the same format of an executable file.

Comment: Yes, i want to extract text resources from .dll file. I don't know whether it is possible or not. That's why i posted on stackoverflow to get experienced answers.

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL was created in .Net, then you can decompile the DLL and browse through the source code. Just do a quick Google search for .Net Decompiler and there should be a few free and paid versions. If it is NOT .Net, then I'm not sure you will have much luck getting anything out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I use .NET Reflector when I want to browse something usually. ([link](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/))